# Why does bulk collect speed up the fetching after opening the cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  TYPE t_bulk_collect_test_tab IS TABLE OF bulk_collect_test%ROWTYPE;
  CURSOR C1 IS SELECT * FROM bulk_collect_test;
  l_tab    t_bulk_collect_test_tab := t_bulk_collect_test_tab();
  l_start  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
  FETCH C1 BULK COLLECT INTO t_bulk_collect_test_tab;
  CLOSE C1;
END;
```

The question is when we open the cursor all the data are taken from database to plsql memory. Before FETCH operation the data is present in
PLSQL memory so there is no question on context switch. Is there any use of this kind of fetch operation?

Comment: No, open a cursor does not read any data from the table. Data is read by fetch.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit what does open statement do?

Comment: OPEN parses the statement, create the execution plan and locks the records (if specified by 'FOR UPDATE')

Answer (score 0):

when you bulk collect a cursor you take the data from DB to an array with one request to db but if you fetch each record in a loop your code send N request to database for fetch records to plsql so it has better performance.
if you have a huge result set you should use '**limit** *NUMBER_OF_RECORDS*' after bulk collect to limit number of records which you want load from DB to pl/sql "see line 9 of following code";
opening a cursor does not load any data to memory it just create a pointer to first record of result set.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  TYPE t_bulk_collect_test_tab IS TABLE OF bulk_collect_test%ROWTYPE;
  CURSOR C1 IS SELECT * FROM bulk_collect_test;
  l_tab    t_bulk_collect_test_tab := t_bulk_collect_test_tab();
  l_start  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
  FETCH C1 BULK COLLECT INTO t_bulk_collect_test_tab limit 500;
  CLOSE C1;
END;
```